# Vuforia VWS and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, web-services, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am trying to access Vuforia VWS through Unity.
I keep getting timeout.

Can I even access the Vuforia webservice from Unity?

If I can, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
string CAK = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
string CSK = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
byte[] myBinaryImage = File.ReadAllBytes(myImgName);
string myURL = "cloudreco.vuforia.com/v1/query";    
string myHTTP_Verb = "POST";
string myContent_MD5 = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e";
string myContent_Type = "multipart/form-data";
string myDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
string myRequest_Path = "cloudreco.vuforia.com/v1/query";
string StringToSign = myHTTP_Verb + "\n" + myContent_MD5 + "\n" + 
myContent_Type + "\n" + myDate + "\n" + myRequest_Path;
var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1 { Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CSK) };
byte[] hashBytes = 
hmacsha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StringToSign));
string cipherBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddBinaryData("image", myBinaryImage);
form.AddField("max_num_results", "10");
form.AddField("include_target_data", "all");

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(myURL, form);
www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "VWS{" + CAK + "}:{" + cipherBytes 
+ "}");
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
}
www.Dispose();
```